# Issue with Airflow Scheduler

Tags: airflow, scheduler

I am new to Airflow and have recently started exploring this tool.I have installed version 1.10.10 in ubuntu machine which is of 18.4 version.From the setup and installation perspective everything is working fine, **but none of my tasks in any DAG are running they are always in queue state as shown in the Airflow WebUI**.

When I looked at the the Task Instance Details I found the state of Task Instance as : **Task is in the 'None' state which is not a valid state for execution. The task must be cleared in order to be run.**

Have tried almost all the options present in **https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/faq.html#why-isn-t-my-task-getting-scheduled** , but nothing seems to be working.

Log file of the tasks shows this :

INFO - Number of active dag runs reached max_active_run.
INFO - Skipping SLA check for <DAG: my_dag> because no tasks in DAG have SLAs

Looking for some help here.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure whether this is the problem in your case, but I've seen the same message:

```
Task is in the 'None' state which is not a valid state for execution. The task must be cleared in order to be run.
```

which in my case was combined with the following message:

```
Task's DAG 'dag_name_here' is paused.
```

This was caused by the ON/OFF switch you can see in the Airflow DAGs overview page. That's a toggle to pause a DAG. In my case the toggle was set to OFF, and so the DAG was paused. Turning the toggle to ON, made my DAG run properly.